# Conditional join of table based on existence of value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

In our datamodel there is a Person.

A Person lives in a House.

A Person can have one 'Subscription'. (It's not relevant what a Subscription constitutes)

A House can have one 'Subscription'.

A Subscription has a SubscriptionNumber.

So, this datamodel allows a Person to have subscriptions directly, but also via their House.

Now for the query.

If the Person has a subscription via their House, then the SubscriptionNumber associated with that Subscription needs to end up in the result. If this is not the case, then the SubscriptionNumber associated with the Subscription directly related with the Person needs to end up in the result (or NULL if that doesn't exist either).

The result of this query will be shown in a grid. We allow users to specifiy filtering and ordering on this column. This implies a couple of things:

```
1)    We cannot simply specify a CASE in the 'main' select statement and alias that result, 
      because this disallows us to filter on it, since WHERE is processed before SELECT. 
2)    For the filtering to be meaningful the result has to be 'put' in one alias
```

I'm really new to DB development and totally stuck, but this is what I've come up with until now:

```
1)    Using a query like this:

      SELECT 
           (CASE 
               WHEN (House of person has subscription)
               THEN (return subscription number of house)
               ELSE (return subscription number of person)
            END) AS SubscriptionNumber
      This leaves me with the exception regarding the unknown column when i try to apply ordering   on SubscriptionNumber. Is there some way to avoid this?


2)    Joining the 2 tables in the FROM list:
      ...
      FROM People
      JOIN (...) AS HouseSubscriptionNumber
      JOIN (...) AS PersonSubscriptionNumber

      This leaves me with 2 seperate columns, which also disallows my ordering.
```

What I'm, conceptually, looking for is some method to extract either one based on its existence.
I've been fumbling with sub queries and unions and all sorts of stuff, but I always get to some sort of brain-loop :-( For example, I could write something like:

```
FROM People 
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        SubscriptionNumber = 
            CASE ...
            END)
```

But how would I join this to the main query?

Lots of questions!
Is there some way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way to use Method 1 in your example is `CROSS APPLY`.  `CROSS APPLY` is processed with the `FROM` clause and any aliases in it can be reused just like a column name in a normal table:

```
SELECT 
...
CxA.SubscriptionNumber
FROM
    MyTables
CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT CASE 
        WHEN (House of person has subscription)
        THEN (return subscription number of house)
        ELSE (return subscription number of person)
    END) CxA(SubscriptionNumber)
```

In the example `CxA` is just an alias for the `CROSS APPLY` expression (just like a table alias, make it anything you want), and SubscriptionNumber is the column alias.

Comment: After some testing this turned out to be a more orderly and flexible solution for my needs, hence the change in accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

The relationships are made up because I do not have your table definitions.
What this does is, it goes to the person table joins onto the house table and finds the subscription number (if it exists If it doesnt exist it will return null). It will also go to the subscription table via the personID and find a subscription (if exists, if it doesnt it too shall return null)

Then we use [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) to find the first non null number. IF both subscriptions do not exist it will return -1

```
SELECT COALESCE (su.SubscriptionNumber,s.subscriptionNumber,-1) as Target
FROM Person AS p 
INNER JOIN house AS h ON p.houseid = h.houseid --assuming a person can only live in 1 house

LEFT JOIN Subscription AS s ON p.subscriptionNumber = s.SubscriptionNumber
LEFT JOIN Subscription AS su ON h.SubscriptionNubmer = su.SubscriptionNumber
ORDER BY target DESC
```

If you want it in a where clause

```
SELECT TARGET FROM (
    SELECT COALESCE (su.SubscriptionNumber,s.subscriptionNumber,-1) as Target
    FROM Person AS p 
    INNER JOIN house AS h ON p.houseid = h.houseid --assuming a person can only live in 1 house

    LEFT JOIN Subscription AS s ON p.subscriptionNumber = s.SubscriptionNumber
    LEFT JOIN Subscription AS su ON h.SubscriptionNubmer = su.SubscriptionNumber
) as mark
WHERE MARK.TARGET = XXXX
```

Comment: Doesn't this impose the same problem I mentioned? If a user were to order on the column, what value should he put in?

Comment: To further clarify: I can't use this column in the where clause.

Comment: @apeiron this will let you order by

Comment: @Apeiron, you can use `COALESCE(su.SubscriptionNumber, s.subscriptionNumber)` in the `WHERE`.

Comment: @ypercube, I chose not to put the COALESCE in the where clause because i dont know if sql server will cache the value. What I think will happen but have 0 proof is the function will run twice for every column once in the where clause and once in the select clause, resulting in a worse execution plan. Again I have no proof just a gut feeling. Do you know if the function will be executed twice?

Comment: No, if you put the same exact expression in the `WHERE` and `SELECT` clauses, it will probably be evaluated once. But it really depends on the actual execution plan. In some cases, the same part of a query may be evaluated multiple times (say in a parallel execution), even if it is mentioned only once in the SQL code.

Comment: After some testing I decided accept the answer involving CROSS APPLY as my definite answer as it provided more flexibility in my use case.